# error in the verification of a select in a form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a form with multiple choices. What I'm trying to do is the following:

I want my form choices not to be repeated, I mean, if I choose one option, it can't be chosen again. I have the following javascript code, but when I choose any option, the alert goes on.

Does anybody what error does my code have?
Feel free to ask anything you want

```
<script>
function validar(){

  var pad_gris = $("#id_nota_pad_gris").val();
    var pad_verde = $("#id_nota_pad_verde").val();
    var pad_azul = $("#id_nota_pad_azul").val();
    var pad_rojo = $("#id_nota_pad_rojo").val();
    var pad_amarillo = $("#id_nota_pad_amarillo").val();

      if ((pad_verde == pad_gris) || (pad_gris == pad_verde)){
        alert("Seleccione valores distintos !!");
        //reset form
        document.getElementById('formulario').reset();
      }

        else if ((pad_azul == pad_verde) || (pad_verde == pad_azul)){
        alert("Seleccione valores distintos !!");
        //reset form
        document.getElementById('formulario').reset();
      }
        else if ((pad_verde == pad_amarillo) || (pad_amarillo == pad_verde)){
            alert("Seleccione valores distintos !!");
            //reset form
            document.getElementById('formulario').reset();
        }
        else if ((pad_verde == pad_rojo) || (pad_rojo == pad_verde)){
            alert("Seleccione valores distintos !!");
            //reset form
            document.getElementById('formulario').reset();
        }
        else if ((pad_gris == pad_azul) || (pad_azul == pad_gris)){
            alert("Seleccione valores distintos !!");
            //reset form
            document.getElementById('formulario').reset();
        }
        else if ((pad_gris == pad_amarillo) || (pad_amarillo == pad_gris)){
            alert("Seleccione valores distintos !!");
            //reset form
            document.getElementById('formulario').reset();
        }
        else if ((pad_gris == pad_rojo) || (pad_rojo == pad_gris)){
            alert("Seleccione valores distintos !!");
            //reset form
            document.getElementById('formulario').reset();
        }
        else if ((pad_zul == pad_amarillo) || (pad_amarillo == pad_azul)){
            alert("Seleccione valores distintos !!");
            //reset form
            document.getElementById('formulario').reset();
        }
        else if ((pad_zul == pad_rojo) || (pad_rojo == pad_azul)){
            alert("Seleccione valores distintos !!");
            //reset form
            document.getElementById('formulario').reset();
        }
        else if ((pad_amarillo == pad_rojo) || (pad_rojo == pad_amarillo)){
            alert("Seleccione valores distintos !!");
            //reset form
            document.getElementById('formulario').reset();
        }

}//end function validar
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please provide your markup as well.

Comment: This isn't the reason for the problem, but each of your "or" operators (`||`) is redundant. The expressions on either side are identical.

Comment: In fact the whole thing could be replaced by `values = Set.new(pad_verde, pad_azul, pad_gris, pad_amarillo, pad_rojo); if (values.size < 5) {...};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dare to assume that you call a function every time you change any form field.And when you change the value of the first variable, the others have the same default value.